# Apache Flink: AND conditions in CEP Patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm new to Apache Flink and the CEP library. I have two (or more) patterns that use data from different sources. 
If the two patterns have matching events, I want to send and alert, but the order of matching does not matter, that is, 
I want an alarm to be sent only when both patterns are match, regardless of whether one was followed first and then the other. Something like an "AND operation" between patterns. I was doing a bit of research and I only find one "OR operation". In the APache Flink code, there is an AndCondition.java class but it seems not to use it in the same way as OrCondition.java ... is there a Flink solution for this case?
A user posted this question a few months ago
 [Apache Flink: Combine CEP Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779218/apache-flink-combine-cep-patterns)

And I'm with the same problem, but no one answered that question ... Thanks for the help and patience!